# C++ Qt: set a active widget in QStyledItemDelegate::paint method

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to set a widget in a treeviews child row using a QStyledItemDelegate.
The widget is shown as intended but not clickable. It seems like it is not "active".

[image]

This is my paint method:

```
ProjectSpecificDelegate::ProjectSpecificDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

void ProjectSpecificDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);

    if(index.data(SpecialTreatmentsArchiv::ParentRowRol).toString() != "parent")
    {
        if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
        {
            painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());
        }

        QPaintDevice* original_pdev_ptr = painter->device();
        QList<ProjectSpecificArchivItem> item_list = index.data(SpecialTreatmentsArchiv::ChildRowRole).value<QList<ProjectSpecificArchivItem> >();

        ProjectSpecificArchiv expand_widget(item_list);

        painter->end();

        expand_widget.render(painter->device(), QPoint(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y()), QRegion(0, 0, option.rect.width(), option.rect.height()), QWidget::DrawChildren);

        painter->begin(original_pdev_ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

My question is: What do I have to change so that it is possible to to interact with the widget?

Comment: Your widget seem to appear as an image, so that you cannot interact with it. I would suggest override `QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor()` function that will return your `expand_widget`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This seems to work but my widget only appears when I click on the child row. Is it possible to show it whenever I expand the parent row?

Comment: Do you keep both paint() and createEditor() functions implementation? Pain renders the delegate, and createEditor returns widget for interaction when your node is in edit mode. You need, to combine these two concepts.

Comment: Hm. I can display the widget without the paint function. When I expand a parent row and click on it I can see my widget. I do not want to edit data. I just want a nice looking way to display my data.

Comment: I want that my widget is created for every child rows. But not only if I click on it. Any ideas?